# Is there a way of monitoring opened files and disk bandwidth for my python script?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, file, bandwidth, hard-drive

My EC2 instance on AWS shows very high read disk bandwidth usage during execution of my python script.

Sometimes i run into problems where i used up all my burst_balance credits for this volume and my hole system gets unstable and basically unusable. We are using the default ubuntu 18.04 image from aws.

Is there a way in python or from the system to get a list of opened files and also maybe the bandwidth used for reading those files.

I can not show the code since it is a quit big python programm and i dont have a clue where the big spike of arround 130MiB/s is comming from.

i know i read from around 200 files which are between 80 and 300 kB in size, but i can not imagine this to give me 130MiB/s for over half an hour.

Can someone point me to a library or system command where i can track down this read bandwidth issue?